# DB connection works from the CLI, but fails from within Drupal

Tags: 7, database

I have set up a MySQL server on a machine with IP-address `192.0.2.9` (not the real address). The database user is named "drupal". Connecting to it using the CLI *mysql* command works just fine and the connection is accepted.

```
mysql -u drupal -p -h 192.0.2.9
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
...
```

However, when Drupal tries to connect to the *same* MySQL server from the *same* host, using the *same* credentials, I get this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.0.2.9' (9)
in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/html/includes/lock.inc).
```

I have double checked that the correct database credentials and host are set in `settings.php`. I am at my wit's end, unable to figure out why this database connection works from the CLI, but not from within Drupal.

In case it matters: This is Drupal 7.41 and the OS on both machines is RHEL7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

The client computer was running SELinux and was blocking outgoing connections over http. This pair of CLI command fixed it.

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```